# How to fetch user info from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

i want to fetch user info here is my url

```
return Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + MyFacebook.AppID + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("h" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Substring("h", "/Membership") + returnUrl) + "%3F__provider__%3Dfacebook&scope=email,read_friendlists,friends_about_me,friends_activities,friends_birthday,friends_checkins,friends_education_history,friends_events,friends_games_activity,friends_groups,friends_hometown,friends_interests,friends_likes,friends_location,friends_notes,friends_online_presence,friends_photo_video_tags,friends_photos,friends_relationship_details,friends_relationships,friends_religion_politics,friends_status,friends_subscriptions,friends_videos,friends_website,friends_work_history");
```

Please let me know where to give permission and what permission on facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to take a look at the Facebook docs, a lot of important information in there.

- It´s always easier to use one of the SDKs for development: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/other-sdks
- The Login process is explained in detail here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.0
- "friend" permissions are deprecated, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog